# NestJS Prisma ORM. Select specific fields

Tags: sql, nestjs, prisma

There are two tables sim_card and observation 1 to 1.
It is necessary to select all SIM cards with the status Active (true) and which are not used in the observation table. (That is, an observation card is created and a free and active SIM card is issued to it.)

```
model observation {
  id         Int       @id @unique @default(autoincrement()) @map("observation_id")
  number     Int
  contract   String?
  sim_card   sim_card? @relation(fields: [sim_cardId], references: [id], map: "ObservationId_sim_card_key")
  sim_cardId Int?      @unique(map: "ObservationId_sim_card_key")
  firmId     Int?      @unique(map: "Observation_firmId_key")
  client     client?   @relation(fields: [firmId], references: [id], map: "Observation_firmId_key")
}


model sim_card {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  number      String       @unique(map: "Sim_card_number_key")
  operator    String       @default("kyivstar")
  active      Boolean      @default(true)
  busy        Boolean      @default(false)
  observationId Int?
}
```

As I imagine, (but it doesn't work)

```
findActive(): Promise<CreateSimCardDto[]> {
        return Promise
            .resolve(this.prismaService.sim_card
                .findMany({
                    where: {
                        active: true
                    },
                    include: {
                        observation: {
                            select: {
                                sim_card: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }))
            .catch((error) => {
                throw new HttpException(error.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select any SIM Card that is not in the observations table, why not search for SIM cards where `observationId` is absent?

```js
this.prismaService.sim_card.findMany({
    where: {
        active: true,
        observationId: { equals: null }
    },
}))
```

`observationId` will be `null` if a given `sim_card` row is not connected to any `observation` rows. Let me know if I didn't understand you correctly, but at the end of the day if you are trying to exempt rows, it needs to be added to your `where` filter. `select` and `include` are only used AFTER the initial filtering has been done - `select` and `include` just determine what fields on the already-filtered rows get returned.